# Zero-padding for ResNet shortcut connections when channel number increase

Tags: python, theano, keras

I would like to implement the ResNet network  in Keras with the shortcut connections that add zero entries when features/channels dimensions mismatch according to the original paper:

> When the dimensions increase (dotted line shortcuts in Fig. 3), we
>   consider two options: (A) The shortcut still performs identity
>   mapping, with extra zero entries padded for increasing dimensions ...
>   http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf

However wasn't able to implement it and I can't seem to find an answer on the web or on the source code. All the implementations that I found use the 1x1 convolution trick for shortcut connections when dimensions mismatch.

The layer I would like to implement would basically concatenate the input tensor with a tensor with an all zeros tensor to compensate for the dimension mismatch.

The idea would be something like this, but I could not get it working:

```
def zero_pad(x, shape):
    return K.concatenate([x, K.zeros(shape)], axis=1)
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to implement such a layer ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was answered on github:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2608

It would be something like this:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras import backend as K


def zeropad(x):
    y = K.zeros_like(x)
    return K.concatenate([x, y], axis=1)


def zeropad_output_shape(input_shape):
    shape = list(input_shape)
    assert len(shape) == 4
    shape[1] *= 2
    return tuple(shape)


def shortcut(input_layer, nb_filters, output_shape, zeros_upsample=True):
    # TODO: Figure out why zeros_upsample doesn't work in Theano
    if zeros_upsample:
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,1),
                             strides=(2,2),
                             border_mode='same')(input_layer)
        x = Lambda(zeropad, output_shape=zeropad_output_shape)(x)
    else:
        # Options B, C in ResNet paper...
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, even in lazy (non-eager) evaluation mode, and does ***not*** require access to another tensor with correct padding (such as with `zeros_like`). `D` is the desired number of channels, `nn` is the tensor we're trying to pad.

```
def pad_depth(nn,D):
    import tensorflow as tf
    deltaD= D- nn.shape[-1]
    paddings= [[0,0]]* len(nn.shape.as_list())
    paddings[-1]= [0,deltaD]
    nn= tf.pad(nn,paddings)
    return nn
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are still looking for it in my GitHub repository I implemented it. Please take a look to https://github.com/nellopai/deepLearningModels.
All the solutions that I found online were not really working and not coherent with the ResNet paper. In the repo you find more details in code/networks/resNet50 . The correct method to implement is:

```
  def pad_depth(x, desired_channels):
        new_channels = desired_channels - x.shape.as_list()[-1]
        output = tf.identity(x)
        repetitions = new_channels/x.shape.as_list()[-1]
        for _ in range(int(repetitions)):
            zeroTensors = tf.zeros_like(x, name='pad_depth1')
            output = tf.keras.backend.concatenate([output, zeroTensors])
        return output
```